# How to keep java.lang.reflect when use proGuard?

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

In my application I want use this **library** : https://github.com/xmuSistone/AndroidPileLayout

And I want use `proguard` in my project, when `proguard` my project show me may bugs.

For fix `proguard`, the library developer say:

> proguard works wrong when you are using java.lang.reflect api, please
>   check your own code.

**My proguard rules :**

```
#--------Glide--------
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
#--------Glide transformations--------
-dontwarn jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.**
#--------Retrofit--------
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn com.squareup.retrofit2.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
#--------Gson--------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
#--------ButterKnife--------
# Retain generated class which implement Unbinder.
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }
# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
#--------MyCustomViews--------
-keep class com.app.app.view.** { *; }
-keep class com.app.app.api.models.** { *; }
-keep class java.lang.reflect.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class java.lang.reflect.**
```

How can I fix it and keep `java.lang.reflect`?

Please help me

Please help me

Comment: https://github.com/xmuSistone/AndroidPileLayout/issues/18

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, In library issue topic developer answered every month! can you help me?

Comment: Can you add your proguard file and how you have used reflect?

Comment: `-keep class java.lang.reflect.** { *; }` ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, i used this code but not work me again

Comment: `-keep class * {
    public private *;
}`

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi, please see my update post

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, please see my update post

Comment: `-dontwarn java.lang.reflect.**`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Ya that might work

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, remove this line : -keep class java.lang.reflect.** { *; } ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, not work me again :( i/m really bad lucky :( :(

Comment: @Hock be cool. Check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons behind getting runtime exceptions may vary depending on the code that you implemented.
One of the reasons behind getting the exception may be relying on field/classes/method names in your code using reflection - ProGuard renames your classes while obfuscating so in order to have them accessible after the obfuscation, they need to be prevented explicitly from the obfuscation.

```
-keep app.package.FancyClass { *; }
```

If it is the library itself that crashes the obfuscated app then I suggest finding the exact place and explicitly keeping the classes that the class where the exception occurs depends on.

The easiest case might be to keep the entire library:

```
-keep com.stone.pile.** { *; }
```

but you can very often configure ProGuard to be more aggressive than that. Nevertheless it's a good starting point.

I think `-keep java.lang.reflect.**` rule does not help much here. The root cause is in the code that relies on class internals that need to be excluded from the obfuscation.

Locate the vulnerable code and try to keep the classes/methods/internals accessed via reflection.

EDIT:
It would be of great help if you pasted the class file with the place where the exception is thrown pointed. The exception message would also add up to the context. Can you do that please?

Comment: Thanks my dear friend, i write below codes in proguard rules for keep my custom views and models. -keep class com.app.app.view.** { *; } -keep class com.app.app.api.models.** { *; } but again not work me :( how can i fix it? can you send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur and really need your help. please :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that you need to keep classes in `java.lang.reflect`, but that somewhere in your code reflection is being used to load, access, and potentially modify classes at runtime.

Because ProGuard and other obfuscators rename your classes to make reverse engineering harder, having a hardcoded classname in a String is going to fail. For example consider this code:

```
com.acme.Acme acme = Class.forName("com.acme.Acme").newInstance();
```

Now consider that after running Proguard on `com.acme.Acme`, it may have been renamed to `a.a.A`. The code would effectively read:

```
a.a.A acme = Class.forName("com.acme.Acme").newInstance();
```

This will result in a `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime, which is why ProGuard will emit a warning or error depending on its configuration.

The solution is to investigate carefully if and where you may be using reflection in your own code, whether you can avoid that reflection, whether it can be ignored, or whether you need to keep the classes that are *being reflected upon*.
In my above example you can avoid trouble by specifying `-keepnames com.acme.Acme`. If reflection is used to instrument on class members, you might need to consider `-keep`ing the entire class and all its members.

But in essence, by definition obfuscation and reflection don't really mix very well.

Comment: Thanks my dear friend, i write below codes in proguard rules for keep my custom views and models. `-keep class com.app.app.view.** { *; }
-keep class com.app.app.api.models.** { *; }` but again not work me :(  how can i fix it? can you send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur and really need your help. please :(

Comment: @Hock Most likely reflection is being used elsewhere. Unfortunately without seeing  your entire source code (which I'm not expecially keen on anyway), I won't be able to do it for you. But if you search for usages of java.lang.reflect within your code, you should be able to find the offending instances quite quickly.

Comment: how can i search java.lang.reflect in my all classes for find this?

Comment: If you use an IDE, it should have such a facility included. Otherwise `grep` on linux or simple Explorer search on Windows should do the trick.